# Can a digital multimeter damage a powered circuit when measuring resistance?

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, resistance, ground, multimeter

I wanted to make sure my ESD wrist-strap is in working order. So I tested like this:

1. Connected the wrist-strap to household ground (via wall socket).
2. Measured the resistance between the wrist-strap and *the exposed ground of my PC's front USB port* (using a non-name brand digital multimeter).

The test worked fine but I realised that the PC was powered on. I've always been told not to measure resistance on a powered circuit because the multimeter applies a voltage to do its measurement.

So, doing what I just did, any chance of damage to the USB port/controller/PC? I don't know enough about electronics to figure this out, though my gut instinct is that tickling ground in the way I did shouldn't matter at all. Still, a definitive answer would be nice!

Comment: Remember the ESD strap should be a high resistance to ground, perhaps 1 MOhm, otherwise you risk a lethal electric shock. You'd still have to touch something live or faulty, but a low resistance strap would guarantee an injury, while you may escape unharmed if not grounded.

Answer (score 2):

The reason not to measure resistance on a powered circuit has more to do with possibly damaging the multimeter because of voltages that are applied from the outside. Because of the way ohmmeters work (they must pass a current through the circuit being measured, so their internal resistance can't be arbitrarily high) it's more difficult to protect them from externally applied voltage.

If the wall sockets are wired properly there's no risk of any damage doing this, but there is an outside chance you might not get an accurate reading because there might be a small voltage present between the two grounds due to some leakage somewhere in your house electrical system.

Why would you not just measure between the ground connection and the strap?

Comment: *Why would you not just measure between the ground connection and the strap?* Meh, good point. I wanted to make sure the PC itself was properly grounded too and that seemed a logical way to do it. Household ground > wrist strap > PC ground.

Answer (score 2):

The thinking is, if you were to measure the value of a resistance, which happened to be at the input of a high power amplifier for example, the voltage injected by the DVM would be interpreted as an input voltage, amplified, and quite possibly blow up the output stage or anything connected to it.

In digital logic this may still happen : the DVM voltage may be mistaken as a logic signal. If that happens to be connected to "output enable" on a bus driver, there is the possibility of damage.

In addition, the bias voltages supplied by the amplifier itself will probably guarantee the resistance reading is wrong anyway.

However, measuring the resistance from one ground connection to another on a powered circuit is unlikely to cause any damage, though it's not best practice.